# How do I create a function / procedure in MariaDB to run an update script when the table got accessed?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have some records in my DB with a special Status let's say `t_status` = 'T' and I want to update each `t_status` which has an `t_moddate` older than 45 minutes to `t_status` = 'X'.

How can i put this into a stored procedure in Maria DB?

My table looks like below:

table name: Test
columns: t_id,t_status,t_moddate,t_usr_update

I guess my update is like below:

`UPDATE TEST SET t_status = 'X' where t_status = 'T' and t_moddate <= now()- interval(45 minutes);`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
     BEGIN

       UPDATE TEST
           SET t_status = REPLACE (first_name, 'T', 'X')
         WHERE t_status = 'T' and t_moddate <= now()- interval 45 minute;

     END$$
```

But how do I get this into a stored procedure to let it run by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [EVENT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-event/) run hourly or whatever interval you choose.
First enable it

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Then write the event proper

```
CREATE EVENT somename
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' HOUR
  STARTS '2017-25-12 00:00:00'    
DO 
UPDATE TEST
       SET t_status = REPLACE (first_name, 'T', 'X')
     WHERE t_status = 'T' AND t_moddate <= now()- interval(45 minutes);
```

Comment: Works that way. Thanks, I had to take off the `STARTS` attribute and needed to change the interval to  `interval 45 minute` than it works nice. Thanks